# Выбор элемента из панели элементов WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

Всем привет! Какой элемент из панели в Winforms надо выбрать, чтобы сделать такой же элемент(см. рисунок)? Сам ничего похожего найти не смог. Элемент взят из Живой геометрии, если что.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать ToggleButton. Чтобы при нажатии на одну кнопку, все другие сбрасывались в Unchecked, а нажатая кнопка имела состояние Checked.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        var checkBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
            checkBox.CheckedChanged += (s, e) => {
                if(((CheckBox)s).Checked) {
                    foreach(var cb in checkBoxes) {
                        if(cb != s)
                            cb.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            };
            checkBoxes.Add(checkBox);
        }
        panel.Controls.AddRange(checkBoxes.ToArray());
        Controls.Add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо `CheckBox` можно использовать `RadioButton`. Тогда становится не нужна обработка события.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, нужно использовать [`ToolStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5daaw6hf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).